# Using Rank vs Max (T-SQL)

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Im currently working on troubleshooting an old job which is taking long in running the query. The old job uses the first query but I have been testing using the second query.

Differences between:

```
Select Max(Cl1) as Tab,
       Max(Cl2) as Tb,
       Customer
From TableA
group by Customer
```

vs

```
Select Customer,
       Tab,
       tb
From 
(Select Customer,
         Tab,
         tb,
         Rank() over (partition by Customer order by Cl1 desc) rk1,
         Rank() over (partition by Customer order by Cl2 desc) rk2
  From TableA) X
 Where X.rk1 = 1 and X.rk2 = 1
```

Tab       Tb     Customer

A45845 100052  Shin

A45845 100053  Shin

A45845 100054  Reek

The table will always have value (no nulls or blank value) for both Tab and Tb columns. Tab is not unique to a particular customer. Tb is a sequential and continuously increasing integer with no duplicates possible (unique). The latest Tab value for a customer will also have the most recent Tb as well.

Though the results are the same, is there something I may not be considering when changing the query in this case?

Edit: Fixed errors on second query when building example and not using real column or table names. Also explanded on scenario. My apologies about the updated info and fix in original post, was called before I even had a chance to double check it.

Comment: The results can only be the same if the same row always has the `MAX()` of both columns. And, in fact, you've forced the second result (due to your `WHERE` clause) to only ever return the values `1,1` for the second and third column. I get the idea you wrote this second query but never actually ran it.

Comment: What is the goal of the query?

Comment: @Love2Learn - it will return 1 row per customer (provided that customer fits the criteria that `MAX(Cl1)` is on the same row as `MAX(Cl2)`) - `PARTITION BY` splits the ranking apart so that each `Customer`'s rows are ranked independently.

Comment: Der, I should probably drink my coffee before replying to threads.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever You are right, I did not run this example which I actually wrote incorrectly and now corrected. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be the equiv query, but I doubt it would be more efficient. @Damien_The_Unbeliever please let me know if I'm wrong again. (Distinct added for the scenario where there are multiple Cl1 and Cl2 rows with the same value. This can be removed if the primary key is across customer, Cl1 and Cl2.)

```
Select  Distinct Customer,
        X.Cl1 as Tab,
        X2.Cl2 as tb
From   (Select  Customer,
                Rank() over (partition by Customer order by Cl1 desc) rk1, 
                Cl1
        From    TableA) X
Join   (Select  Customer,         
                Rank() over (partition by Customer order by Cl2 desc) rk2, 
                Cl2
        From    TableA) X2
        On  X.Customer = X2.Customer
Where   X.rk1 = 1 
And     X2.rk2 = 1
```

Comment: I think this would return the same results as max.  But the question refers to "taking long".   I seriously doubt it would be faster.   That join is going to be bigger than Customer.

Comment: @Blam Agreed, you can't get much simpler than the original query. If it's a performance issue they probably want to look at their indexes on that table. I only included the code logic because they were asking about the disparity between their two queries.

Comment: @Love2Learn Thanks and yes, its more of a disparity question as opposed to performance.

Answer (score 1):

Seriously doubt Rank is going to be faster.

Where you would need rank is if you wanted the value of CL2 on the row where CL1 is max.

Do you have indexes on Customer, CL1, and CL2?
Check fragmentation.
Check the execution plans.

And no way those are returning the same results.

Comment: As Love2Learn noted, it's not a performance issue or question, more of a disparity between both queries. Nonetheless, thanks for the input.

Comment: OK but why the comment "taking long in running the query"?

Answer (score 0):

The first query returns values for `Tab` and `Tb`, the second always returns 1 and 1 for the two columns (because of the `where` clause).

The second will only return customers where there is a row that is the first by both CL1 and Cl2.  The first returns a row for all customers.

The second will return duplicates, when multiple rows satisfy the two ordering conditions for a given customer.  The first returns only one row per customer.

The second has a syntax error, so it will not run (the comma after `rk2`).  The first seems to be valid SQL syntax.

The first seems simpler and more understandable.  However, I think my first point is the biggest difference.  (I'm ignoring the fact that the columns are in different orders.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the syntax errors and identifying the columns. I did that example in a hurry while trying not to use the same column or table names.